# Update existing spreadsheet with ExcelJS

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I have an spreadsheet my company uses to do calculations.  Currently we have an auto hotscript to simulate typing data into the cells.  Once it gets data, the excel does all sorts of calculations.  I am relatively new to node but know enough JS to code. The auto hotkey is not stable enough for what I need.

What I want to know, is if I know the name of this spreadsheet I have, can i somehow open it, and then update any cells I need to update, so the spreadsheet with then do its thing?

I call it update, but I am thinking its called write in excelJS..but to me Update seems like the correct term.

I don't want a new spreadsheet, I want to update an existing one.

I have my environment set up and I want to start, but don't see any code to try that says it will open an existing spreadsheet and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will better to use zapier to connect the spreadsheet api. (Or retool)
Exceljs does not do such work.